# Conflict in selenium's open Chrome instances c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a very simple c# class that creates a chrome instance and executes some js code but for some unknown reasons, when i try to create more then 1 instance of that class the js only gets executed on 1 chrome instance(the last one), all  functions are inside the class,noting is public.
Heres the code

```
    public class Engine
    {
        public Engine()
        {
            var cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(cService, options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someurl");
        }
        public async Task<object> runJs(string js)
        {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
           {
            IJavaScriptExecutor jste = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            return jste.ExecuteScript(js);
           });
        }
    }
```

Calling it:

```
(new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
        {
            engine = new Engine();
            var jsres = await engine.runJs("some simple js code");
            Console.WriteLine(jsres);
            
        })).Start();
```

Comment: just to be clear only the calling function is in a form

Comment: you'd need to include some code here... (especially concerning webdriver initialization,  class constructor, and created class objects/references...)  Seems like you want threading here.

Comment: I don't see a type for "driver" here... defined somewhere else?